# Why does Mattias have a photo?

Tags: frozen-2

At the end of Frozen 2 Mattias and Halima (Mattias long lost wife?) look at a photograph of each other. It strikes me as anachronistic to have photographs in this world. Why was this very minor yet out of place scene included?

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photography):

> The first permanent photoetching was an image produced in 1822 by the French inventor Nicéphore Niépce

See for instance [the daguerreotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daguerreotype):

> the first publicly available photographic process; it was widely used during the 1840s and 1850s.

WRT [when Frozen takes place](https://screenrant.com/frozen-movies-time-period-setting-when/):

> it seems the first Frozen movie is set in the 1860s or 1870s

That article even uses the appearance of the camera to establish this:

> Something else that anchors the franchise's late-1800s setting is the fact that, at the end of *Frozen 2*, a camera is used; the characters are still bewildered by the technology and coming to terms with how to use it. While the oldest surviving photograph dates back to 1826, **cameras started to become more commonly used in the late 19th century when their functionality rapidly started to increase.** This would fit in with the fact that *Frozen* likely takes place in the late 1860s or early 1870s and *Frozen 2* three years after, roughly when cameras would start to be used more in public life and, therefore, establishing the timeline of the franchise.

Comment: Huh, I figured the movie took place much longer ago than that.

Comment: Anna rides a fairly modern-looking bicycle in the first film, so that places it in the mid-to-late 19th century.